# Error installing Geckodriver

Tags: linux, files, kali-linux, tar, wget

I need to download this file : "https://github.com/`curl -s https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases | grep -E -o '/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/[a-z0-9/.-]{5,}linux64.tar.gz' | head -n 1`"

Here is my command:
`` wget -O geckodriver-linux64.tar.gz echo "https://github.com/`curl -s https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases | grep -E -o '/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/[a-z0-9/.-]{5,}linux64.tar.gz' | head -n 1`" ``

I'll enter this next:
`tar xvzf geckodriver-linux64.tar.gz`

after which they give the following error:

````
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now```

I checked the file :

```file geckodriver-linux64.tar.gz
geckodriver-linux64.tar.gz: HTML document, Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with very long lines (1849)```

what's wrong?
````

Comment: The error says that the file you downloaded (`geckodriver-linux64.tar.gz`) is an HTML document and not a zipped TAR archive.  The commands you have posted into the question make no sense to me, I suspect those need to be cleaned up to reflect what you were actually doing.  When I `curl -s https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases`, there are no download links in the page as I believe GitHub uses Javascript to piece that together and `curl` does not process Javascript.

Comment: If you just want to get a release such as the most current, then why not just `wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.33.0/geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server instead of sending you the file, it sends an HTML page to download the file, try downloading it using a web browser and then running tar on it.

Also, the grep command seems to be leading to a folder that should be in GitHub's server and not the local machine.

As an alternative, try downloading the file from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases using a web browser directly and then decompressing with the `tar` command.